# Software for computing geometirc data of parametric surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, math-software

Is there any (possibly free) software suitable for computing geometric quantities of parametric surfaces?

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sage is a free piece of software similar to Mathematica. Check it out [here](http://www.sagemath.org/).

For example, to compute the Gaussian and mean curvatures of the sphere,

```
sage: sphere = surfaces.Sphere(); sphere
sage: K = sphere.gauss_curvature();
sage: H = sphere.mean_curvature();
```

See [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/riemannian_geometry/sage/geometry/riemannian_manifolds/parametrized_surface3d.html) for more functions.

[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19046/open-source-mathematical-software) MO answer also contains many other software links.

[This](https://orms.mfo.de/) link is particularly useful to find software oriented to a particular field.